# How do I send a C program's string to an su password prompt?

Tags: c, system, su

I have changed ubuntu's default root password by :

```
sudo passwd
```

Now, I am designing a C program to brute-force this password. I am using `system()` to call `su`
But `su` prompts for a password directly in the terminal... I want to automate this procedure and automatically input the password...
My Current Code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
    system("su");
}
```

but this asks for a password... I want to automatically specify the password in the program so that `su` does not ask for a password. Any ideas ??????

Comment: Good job for [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: You can use something like [`popen` from GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-to-a-Subprocess.html).

Comment: I believe `popen` or input redirection wont work, since I guess `su` reads on `/dev/tty`

Comment: How to use expect ???

Comment: Can anyone give me detailed steps ???

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you are probably going about this the wrong way.  The proper way to crack a superuser account on a Linux/Unix system is to brute force the hashes in /etc/passwd.

However, if you want to do do this with system commands, you can use [sudo -S](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) and pipe the password to STDIN.

The reason that this doesn't work with `su` is that doing so is disallowed because it is  inherently insecure and dangerous, and therefore `su` doesn't even use STDIN.

Comment: Nobody stores hashes in /etc/passwd anymore.  And typically to read /etc/shadow on Linux, you have to be root or in the shadow group.

Answer (score 0):

Use "sucrack".

Su attempts to enforce usage of a TTY. Simplified a TTY means "an actually user at a 'teletype terminal'" and not a script. But then again its all software and it can all be emulated. sucrack crates a "PTY", a (again simplified) "Pseudo teletype terminal", that is looks identical to the software (su).

So long story short, it can enter passwords using magic and tell you if it finds the password.

Sucrack is available as a ubuntu package, which would require root to install (which you dont have). So an alternative is to compile a static version of sucrack on another system and upload it to the server. It is doable. Hackers do it all the time ;)